# Creating a custom page layout in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

I am a novice user to the SharePoint 2010. I am learning how to create the custom layout for the master page.  I couldn't get any material that is organised. I need to create a master page layout and add content placeholders so that I can a dd web parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becky Bertram wrote also a nice blog post about this several months ago

http://blog.beckybertram.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=71

Her valuable articles are always very handy !